# undoManager used in coredata

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, undo

I have two entities A and B. A has an one-to-many  relationships to B. After I changed some properties in B, how could I undo all the changes in B? I have tried rollback method, but that will affect other properties in A.

Comment: You mean changes might be made to both A and B and you want the undoManager to undo only the changes made to B? (Assuming you don't mean changes to relationship membership, which is reciprocal between A and B.)

Comment: yeap！is there anyway to handle this problem？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `disableUndoRegistration` on the undoManager just before making any change to A, and calling `enableUndoRegistration` just after making any change to A.

Now, where to put this code? Ideally you'd override some method/s in NSManagedObject for your A class, but which ones? I don't think the `validate` methods would work, at least not for disabling the undo registration, because I think the change may already have been registered with the undoManager by the time they are called. It's tempting to use `will/didChangeValueForKey:` -- but the class reference says "You must not override this method."

So I think you're stuck addressing this in any interface action that can affect A.

---

Edit -- Here's the sample you requested:

```
- (IBAction) someAction:(id)sender {
    BOOL isA = NO;
    NSManagedObjectContext currentContext = nil;
    if ([[sender objectControlledBySender] isKindOfClass:[subclassedManagedObjectA class]]) {
        isA = YES;
        currentContext = // get a ref to your current context, or just make it an unretained property of this controller's class
        [currentContext.undoManager disableUndoRegistration];
    }
    // Make the changes to the object accessed via sender.
    if (isA)
        [currentContext.undoManager enbleUndoRegistration];
}
```

The "objectControlledBySender" is necessarily vague, because `sender` could by any kind of control, with any kind of accessors to the objects it displays or edits or selects.

Comment: Could I group some changes and undo all the changes at the same time?

Comment: "Undo *all* the changes"? I thought that was what you wanted to avoid.

Comment: You mean tell the undoManager to undo a particular group of changes, skipping over others? No, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673730/iphone-core-data-to-many-relationship-and-canceling-edits-to-child-objects   this problem is similar and the answer is "There are several ways to solve this problem:

create an additional context for adding the new objects, on cancel dismiss the context, on save merge the context with the main context

Use an undo manager, on cancel revert any changes. Use undo grouping to group all changes" , but i do not know to to use undo grouping

Comment: Is it possible to undo all changes made in one view controller without affect its parent view controller? Even though they are with the same MOC?